# Keeping 2 forms inline

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm currently trying to solve a school work I was assigned with, but I'm struggling to solve a pretty simple issue.

I'm trying to keep a simple html and js calculator and a json table in the same line but I haven't managed to do it yet and I've been trying for a while. I'm leaving only the html code below since the problem is there and not in the scripts. Help appreciated!
PS. Using bootstrap

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Página de teste BOOSTRAP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
    <style>
        .page-footer {
            background-color: #222;
            color: #ccc;
            padding: 60px 0 30px;
        }

        .footer-copyright {
            color: #666;
            padding: 40px 0;
        }

        #tabela {
            height: 100%;
            width:50%;
        }

        #Calc {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="page-header header container-fluid">

        <div class="description">
            <h1>Bem-vindo à minha Landing Page!</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis. Suspendisse consectetur mi id libero fringilla, in pharetra sem ullamcorper.
            </p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <form name="Calculadora">
        <div id="display" class="row mt-5 mb-5 ml-1 mr-1">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="Calc" width="100%" class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr><td colspan="4"><input type="text" id="resultados" class="form-control" /></td></tr>
                                <tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(7);">7</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(8);">8</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(9);">9</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addOperation('+');">+</button></td></tr>
                                <tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(4);">4</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(5);">5</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(6);">6</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addOperation('-');">-</button></td></tr>
                                <tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(1);">1</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(2);">2</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(3);">3</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addOperation('*');">*</button></td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="1"></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addVal(0);">0</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="addOperation('C');">C</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addOperation('/');">/</button></td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="calculate();">=</button></td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form name="tabela">
        <div class="table">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabela" data-height="460">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
                        <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
                        <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Additional Information</h6>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Contact</h6>
                    <p>
                        1640 Riverside Drive, Hill Valley, California
                        <br />info@mywebsite.com
                        <br />+ 01 234 567 88
                        <br />+ 01 234 567 89
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center">© 2020 Copyright: MyWebsite.com</div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="dadostabelas.js"></script>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: It's unclear what you are after here. You posted a large section of code, and it's not clear what the expected and actual results are.  If you can reduce to a small code snippet that you are having a specific issue with, it might be easier to get help.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json table". There's an HTML table, and there's data in JSON  format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section of the official [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) explains that you can achieve this with the `row` and `col-sm` class.

You need to wrap your two forms in a `<div class="row">` and wrap each of them into two `<div class="col-sm">` like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm">
         Left side
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm">
         Right side
   </div>
</div>
```